# XSLT Choose based on a node

Tags: xslt

I have some XML thus

```
<root>
  <TemplateNode>
    <Heading>
      <ID>1</ID>
      <Name>HeadingNodeTest</Name>
      <Order>1</Order>
      <Text>This is a Heading Node</Text>
    </Heading>
  </TemplateNode>
  <TemplateNode>
    <SimpleText>
      <ID>2</ID>
      <Name>PlainTextNode</Name>
      <Order>2</Order>
      <Text>This is some plain text. Blah blah blah .. etc</Text>
     </SimpleText>
  </TemplateNode>
  <TemplateNode>
    <RadioTemplateNode>
```

...etc

I would like to be able to do an xslt choose based on the Heading/SimpleText type bit
for example

```
<xsl:for-each select="TemplateNode">
   <xsl:choose>
       <xsl:when test="TemplateNode/* = Header">
           ..do stuff
       </xsl:when>
       <xsl:when test="TemplateNode/* = SimpleText">
           ..do other stuffstuff
       </xsl:when>
       ...etc
   </xsl:choose>
</xsl:for-each select="TemplateNode">
```

***<xsl:when test="TemplateNode/* = Header">**
can I even do something like this, or am I better off changing the XML to  and selecting on that?

or do I need to set a variable and choose on that..?

thanks
nat

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't adapt your data to your code. If the XML is OK with you, then leave it as it is. This would work, for instance

```
<xsl:for-each select="/root/TemplateNode">
  <xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when test="Heading">
      ..do stuff
    </xsl:when>
    <xsl:when test="SimpleText">
      ..do other stuff
    </xsl:when>
  ...
```

Of course, this only works if the various `TemplateNode` child elements mutually exclude each other. This is another option:

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="/root/TemplateNode/*"/>
```

And then

```
<xsl:template match="/root/TemplateNode/Heading">
    ..do stuff
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="/root/TemplateNode/SimpleText">
    ..do other stuff
</xsl:when>
```

Answer (score 0):

**It is a good principle in XSLT to avoid conditionals as much as possible.**

Instead of

```
<xsl:for-each select="TemplateNode"> 
   <xsl:choose> 
       <xsl:when test="TemplateNode/* = Header"> 
           ..do stuff 
       </xsl:when> 
       <xsl:when test="TemplateNode/* = SimpleText"> 
           ..do other stuffstuff 
       </xsl:when> 
       ...etc 
   </xsl:choose> 
</xsl:for-each select="TemplateNode">
```

**Write**:

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="TemplateNode"/>
```

**And also have these templates**:

```
 <xsl:template match="TemplateNode[Heading]">
  <!-- Processing here -->
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="TemplateNode[SimpleText]">
  <!-- Processing here -->
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="TemplateNode[RadioTemplateNode]">
  <!-- Processing here -->
 </xsl:template>
```

**This code is simpler and easier to understand and maintain**.